# How to attach _meta data to an index in elasticasearch during a _bulk create

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to add [`_meta`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta.html) data to an elasticsearch index during creation. I'm using the elasticasearch.js `_bulk` api for this:

```
var _bulk = [];
_bulk.push({ create: { _index: "myDocuments", _type: "type", _id: "my_id" } });
_bulk.push({ my: "document" });

elasticSearchClient.bulk({ refresh: true, body: _bulk }, function(err, response) { });
```

Where should `_meta` be attached to during this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk request is indexing documents. The `_meta` field is not on the document level, it's on the type level. So, it cannot be added to the bulk request. It can be only created during mapping creation. So, you can do it either directly using  [put mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) command, or indirectly using [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) with appropriate mapping in it.